# Stop Windows from installing outdated OEM drivers for a specific device

Tags: windows, drivers, updates, oem

[Most answers](https://superuser.com/a/1213184) about how to stop this take a shotgun approach and disable updates to *any* drivers on the system, which is not good practice. [The one](https://superuser.com/a/968749/551612) that stops drivers from
being *installed* that works does that, prevent new drivers from installing, but Windows will first uninstall the working driver to then attempt to update it and fail at the install step.

Is there any way to stop Windows from "updating" to outdated OEM drivers for one device in particular?

Answer (score 1):

The only way at hand to stop a single update is to use wushowhide to hide the update. In my experience hiding future updates normally works.

In the article below, go to the section:

**Disable specific updates on Windows 11 from downloading automatically**

[Article for hiding updates](https://pureinfotech.com/disable-automatic-updates-windows-11/)

Go to the Microsoft Download page to download wushowhide file and run it to hide the specific update.

[wushowhide](https://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/2/f22d5fdb-59cd-4275-8c95-1be17bf70b21/wushowhide.diagcab)

I have successfully used this before but have not needed it since drivers for my own computer are current.

If wushowhide does not work for you, you will need to pause all updates for a period of weeks (Windows Update Settings) and log a case with the driver manufacturer to get a better driver.